# Getting BeagleBone to capture a still frame using OpenCV

Tags: linux, opencv, beagleboard, angstrom-linux, video4linux

I've a BeagleBone running [Ångström Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m_distribution) 3.2.28, and I'm trying to capture a frame from my camera.

So I plug in my USB webcam, and check `/dev` to ensure it shows up.

It does, as `video0` (bottom right). I know this is correct, because it disappears after I've unplugged the camera.

[image: (bo]

So now I fire up Python and run the following:

```
root@beaglebone:/dev# python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Sep 11 2012, 16:15:43)
[GCC 4.5.4 20120305 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv
>>> capture=cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)
>>> img=cv.QueryFrame(capture)
>>> type(capture)
<type 'cv2.Capture'>
>>> type(img)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

As you can see, I am able to create the capture object sufficiently, but I am unable to pull a frame from it. I have also tried this with different (or no) integer arguments for the camera ID (the `-1` in the code above) to no avail.

For reference, running the same code on my laptop in [IPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) looks like this:

```
In [1]: import cv
In [2]: capture=cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)
In [3]: img=cv.QueryFrame(capture)
In [4]: type(capture)
Out[4]: cv2.Capture
In [5]: type(img)
Out[5]: cv2.cv.iplimage
```

You can see that here I am indeed capturing an image. I am not sure exactly where to go from here.

UPDATE:

I've played around a bit with [FFmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) and am able to get the camera to respond (that is, its light goes on) by issuing the following command:

```
root@beaglebone:/# ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0
```

Which is interesting because [apparently](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=capturefromcam#capturefromcam) `CaptureFromCAM` uses the V4L interface... I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Does, the camera respond. Some camera models blink their LED light when an image is captured. Did you try working on something like that.

And, what about saving the image?

Comment: Ah, it does not respond... so that's more info but still not sure where to go? I'm fairly new to linux.

Answer (score 2):

The very [first thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919567/176769) [you need to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9640922/176769) is **make sure `CaptureFromCAM()` succeeded**:

```
import cv
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)
if not capture:
    print "Unable to open device #-1"
    sys.exit(1)
```

Sending `-1` as argument tells OpenCV to open the default camera device. On some systems this doesn't work and you need to increase the number. Try passing `0`, then `1` and later `2`.

The **second thing** you need to do is make sure `QueryFrame()` returns something valid as well:

```
img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
if not img:
    print "Unable to retrieve frame from the device"
    sys.exit(1)
```

I've seen strange behaviors between OpenCV's Python API and the C (and even the C++) API. If none of the above help you fix the problem, I suggest you **compile a C program** (which has the most reliable API) using OpenCV to retrieve data from the camera. On some cases, OpenCV's C API work and the Python doesn't.

[This C program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5385662/176769) retrieves frames from the camera and displays them in a window:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cv.h>

int main() 
{
CvCapture* capture = NULL;
if ((capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1)) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n"); 
    return -1;
}

cvNamedWindow("mywindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

cvQueryFrame(capture); // Sometimes needed to get correct data

while (1) 
{     
    IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture); // check return
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: cvQueryFrame failed\n");
        break;
    }

    // At this point you already have the frame! There's no need to
    // repeat the thing 10x with cvGrabFrame and cvRetrieveFrame. 
    // You are probably sabotaging yourself doing this multiple times.

    cvShowImage("mywindow", frame); // Do not release the frame!

    int key = cvWaitKey(10);
    if (key  == 0x1b)
        break;
}    

cvReleaseCapture(&capture);   
cvDestroyWindow("mywindow");   

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The python code you write is equivalent to the steps I went through, and I return the same result.  Trying to compile the C-code you linked to (note: I don't know any C) returns (note, i named the file temp.c)....... temp.c:1:10: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*'                   token

Comment: Sorry about that, that code is missing the `main()` function. I added the full application in my answer. Let me know if you have any more compiling issues.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this can be an answer. Do try out the following.

I guess, the camera driver is not supported. Connect the camera onto the board and type 'dmesg' in the terminal, and see whether the camera manufacturers name is detected in it.

If the manufacturers name is not present anywhere in the message, the camera driver is to be installed from the terminal:

```
opkg update
opkg install kernel-module-uvcvideo
modprobe uvcvideo
```

If the above steps doesn't help you, try installing [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player) or any other player which supports video input from a camera, and try whether it's working. :)

Comment: I know the camera is working (at least on my windows box). I did as you instructed by installing the uvcvideo module, still not working... any other suggestions (i'm still digging in the meantime)

Comment: So should I see anything specific after I run `modprobe uvcvideo`?

Comment: You must be seeing something like: video capture interface: v2.00;
registered new interface driver uvcvideo;
Video Class driver (1.1.1)
This will ensure that the driver is installed correctly

Comment: Connecting the camera should print the model details of the cam in terminal. If it doesnot, do 'dmesg' and see whether the last few lines show something like: 

usb 1-2.1: Product: Webcam C110

Comment: Lets not complicate things up by searching for the problem from scratch. Showing me the output of 'modprobe uvcvideo' and 'dmesg' might give us a clue to your problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use any V4L2 application and try to test the camera without using any code. There is Qt V4L2 software that you can download and test the camera with.
2. If step one fails, then there are problems with your camera driver, and it is not supported.
3. If step one succeeds then check your code and try to use gstreamer or any ready V4L2 capture samples.

I have faced problems that the camera can be recognized, but the driver has bugs, so check first if the camera's driver is really supported by your kernel. Mentioning your camera model is also good. What kind of interface is it, [MIPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_Serial_Interface) or USB? I suspect that that's a driver problem.